# Fatal error: Call to a member function stmt_init() on a non-object

Tags: php

I'm still struggling with my `getSitename` function.

Today's error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function stmt_init() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ruby\app\includes\classes\class.core.php on line 22
```

Los code:

```
public function getHotelname($conn) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT value FROM cms_functions WHERE title = 'sitename' ");
    $stmt->stmt_init();
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($sitenaam);
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($stmt->fetch) {
            return $sitenaam;
        }
    }
}
```

Any answers?

Comment: Your prepare() call is failing. [RTFM on the return value section to debug](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: @MikeB Lol, can you see what part is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the OO method of `MySQLi` library - incorrectly.

Please refer to this on how to use prepare correctly: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

In your code, you are passing the `$conn` object as a param to the function. Instead; why don't you load it using `global`?

Here's a possible solution for your function:

```
public function getHotelname($title) {
    global $conn;
    $sitenaam = null;
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT value FROM cms_functions WHERE title = ?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $title);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($sitenaam);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
    }
    return $sitenaam;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo getHotelname('sitename');
```

Comment: I had a typo in the code. `if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(` should be `if ($stmt = $conn->prepare(` - answer updated.

Comment: @Latheen Kanes When I do that I get the famous "White Screen Of Death"

Comment: The error message is being generated, but not being displayed. Can you set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and change `display_errors` to `On` and restart your apache (or php-fpm). Or do it inline using `ini_set` - alternatively, check your `php-errors.log` file on your server. See what the error is...

Answer (score 0):

Method `stmt_init()` is from class `Mysqli` (http://www.php.net/manual/bg/mysqli.stmt-init.php)

But, prepare, returns a Statement object (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

You should class `stmt_init()` from the mysqli object, which, I suppose is `$conn` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not totally getting you here. Can you explain it a little bit further?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this:

```
$stmt->stmt_init();
```

The error is generated because $stmt must contain a pointer to a class that contains the function named stmt_init, and in your problem, $stmt does not.